# What is the use of ICache<TK, TV> WithNoRetries() method and how and when to use it?

Tags: ignite

I am using Ignite.Net and I have a very simple use case, wherein I want to put something into the cache without any transaction using CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC, to achieve that I am trying to use putIfAbsentAsync(key,Value) method.

But having a look at the description of the method on
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#putIfAbsentAsync-K-V- page, I am a bit confused!
Being new to Ignite can you please help me understand this better?Below are my doubts.

Description of putIfAbsentAsync method in the above link states the below

"*For CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC return value on primary node crash may be incorrect because of the automatic retries.It is recommended to disable retries with withNoRetries() and manually restore primary-backup consistency in case of update failure.*"

- Can you please explain what are automatic retries ? How and when to use it ?
- What are pros and cons of disabling retries with withNoRetries() ?
- I am also using ReplaceAsync(), RemoveAsync() And PutIfAbsentAsync() with the same cache configuration. Will there be any impact on the functionally of these functions after disabling retries?
- What are the possible scenarios where in primary node may crash?
- In what scenarios will putIfAbsentAsync() return false?
- In what scenarios will putIfAbsentAsync() throw an exception? And List of all  possible exception ? 
  I know the above link states the list of exceptions 
  (TransactionTimeoutException,TransactionRollbackException,TransactionHeuristicException) But all three are related to Transactions ! I don't really understand why Transaction exception will be thrown in ATOMIC mode, as there aren't any transactions in ATOMIC mode ?
- I tried another use case have just one server node and one client node. Server Node creates and stores the cache and client Node just puts or gets cache  ,When I manual stopped the server node just before a client node was trying to put something in the cache I got SocketException i.e java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed Exception. If this is a valid use case it would be better if you list these exception on the page.
- I don't understand this line *"manually restore primary-backup consistency in case of update failure*" can you please explain what is primary-backup consistency ? and how to manually restore it ?

Answer (score 2):

`withNoRetries()` just disallows retries. If operation fails, you get exception promptly. This compared to default behavior where operation will be retried until it is possible.

See more about [ATOMIC limitations](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html#ATOMIC) and [IEP-12](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-12+Make+ATOMIC+caches+consistent+again) in the docs. Note that normally this is only possible when more than one node leaves cluster at once.